# Chrome, Firefox and IE all blank pages

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet, internet-explorer-8, blank-screen

IE, Chrome and Firefox are, no matter what page I go to, coming up blank. No content whatsoever.

If you view source in all three browsers it is blank.

Yet, if you use Wireshark the appropriate packets seem to be being sent and received.

I've done the following:

- ipconfig /flushdns
- netsh winsock reset catalog
- netsh int ip reset C:/reset.log hit
- Virus scan with NOD32.
- Disabled anti-virus completely.
- Checked proxy settings. 
  (as I said above, Wireshark is telling me that the appropriate packets are being sent and received from i.e. google, so I think that rules out a proxy problem)

And none of it seems to have alleviated the problem.

Anybody got any suggestions on what the problem may be?

Comment: 1) Check your proxy settings; 2) Disable antivirus during a test (especially HTTP/Web traffic scanner).

Comment: Had done both of the above before posting, but forgot to mention. Edited original post to correct.

Answer (score 0):

It must be OS related.  Try running [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see what DLLs are shared between these 3 browsers.  Maybe one of the drawing libraries being used is corrupt or an alternate DLL is in the path and getting picked up before the proper one.

Try booting into Safe Mode to see if that helps.  At least you'll be able to isolate the problem somewhat.

What OS is it?